# Bandwidth Calculation in Mbps

Tags: linux, unix, bandwidth

Can someone check this calculation?

I want to calculate the speed of my internet connection by downloading a file from a remote server.

My time unit is in 1/60th of a second. Let's say the file on the remote server is 32K.

> timeBegin = ticks <- 1/60th of a second since beginning
>   of some date
>   get.url( file )
>   timeEnd =
>   ticks
>
> Mbps = ( size of file * 8) /  ( timeEnd -
>   timeBegin ) / 60 / 1048576

Does anyone know of a way to test bandwidth (upload/download) from the command line (unix)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is not quite correct, you are missing some parentheses.

```
Mbps = ( size of file * 8) / ( ( timeEnd - timeBegin ) / 60 ) / 1048576
```

I see DasBoot already pointed out some of the potential sources of inaccuracy in this method. I'll just add to #2 that the critical bandwidth limitation may also exist at some hop in between you and the server.

Comment: Thanks, but not worried about limitations at this point. This isn't mission critical. Just need ballpark.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the exact command off the top to do what you want.
But, you may not get a very accurate reading of your internet BW based on this test.

There are 2 issues I see:

1) You could be limited by latency. Download time is a factor of both latency (the amount of time for a packet to do a round trip between source and destination) and BW.

2) The server and not you may have limited BW.

You probably can get a more accurate number by checking out sights like this:
[speakeasy](http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/)

Comment: Need to do it via command line. Not so much worried about latency. I know it's a factor, I can adjust for this. Not worried about server since file isn't that large.

Answer (score 0):

One way I use to check "bandwidth" between servers is to look at the results from scp between remote and local (and vice versa). You could also consider using a large file like 30-40MB...
Another way is to use the wget command which show the speed of download too (like 1Mb/s)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [IPTRAF](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/04/iptraf-reliable-network-monitoring.html) to monitor it.